# changing fonts in vimrc

Tags: vimrc, font

[image]
[image]

[image]

The last pic is the info I got from Hacking Vim. How do I solve the error - the top pic is my vimrc.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please try to post actual text rather than picutres of text whenever possible... That makes it easier on users who may have trouble with the size or formatting of text in the pictures. It also makes it much easier to copy & paste script snippets whenever needed. And by posting text, it's also possible to reformat or reword parts of it to improve clarity in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the font size you need to prefix the size with an "h", so the correct command would be `:set guifont=Courier:h14`.